# Sign a VBA macro with a level 2 certificate

Tags: vba, code-signing, digital-certificate

I am trying to sign my excel VBA code.  As I understand, I can do this with "level 2" or "class 2"

I'm trying to find something cheeper than go-daddy, $200 per year seems a bit steep for this service.

StartSSL Their website says "object code signing" http://www.startssl.com/?app=39

There is a nice how to for the code signing here: https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1654

However, nothing specifies that you can sign Excel macros.

I can't be the first person to deal with this... but I have been googling for 2 hours to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to do it on your own or looking for a *cost effective* service? :)

Comment: I'm definitely looking for something cost effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, according to their help email is that yes, this certificate will work.

My email:

```
Hello there Kirill,

If I sign my Excel 2010 VBA macro with your StartSSL Level 2 certificate, will the users of my spreadsheets see any warning?
```

Their Response:

```
No, should not if correctly signed.

-- 
Regards

Signer:     Eddy Nigg, COO/CTO
    StartCom Ltd.
Twitter:    Follow StartSSL™
XMPP:   help@startcom.org
Phone:  +1.213.341.0329
    +1.347.534.2026
    +44.20.799.34541
    +972.8.634.4170
```

PS.  Formatting on this site is weird.

Comment: Are you going through this process to sell a product and deploy to other users (and have a professional outcome where there is no prompt or certificate warning), or do you want to just get rid of annoying security warnings with a few workarounds? In other words what kind of end user do you anticipate? If you are the only user then just generate your own and import it into the certificate store to make it trusted.

Personally I have an issue paying someone an expensive ongoing fee for a certificate when I can generate my own and save it to the certificate store and make it trusted.

Comment: In fact there is a 'certificate generation' tool that comes with VBA. Use that to generate your certificate and you can use that to sign your code. Then optionally you can import it into the certificate store to make it trusted.

Comment: Thanks Electric! Unfortunately, I fall into the category of someone who is looking for a professional outcome.  It is a bit expensive, but StartCom is offering the certificates for $60, which is hugely cheaper than its competitors, and since my software will be used by engineers, I think the investment will be worth it.

Comment: If you want to go professional then yes you'll have to buy one. I have heard of free trusted certificates but all my research on the web has just turned up dodgy certificate sellers. It's such a scummy business.

Answer (score 1):

any code signing certificate can be used to sign an excel macro.

You can use a self signing certificate if you don't mind people getting a warning every time that the code is self signed.

In excel 2010, you can go here:
[image: menu showing signing]

to add your purchased certificate, or create a self signed certificate